# linker script error invalid syntax error

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

linker script throwing error but i think there is no

the code casing error is:

```
SECTIONS
{

ENTRY(_entry)

/DISCARD/ : {
    *(.note*);
    *(.iplt*);
    *(.igot*);
    *(.rel*);
    *(.comment);
    *(.eh_frame);
}

. = 0x600;

.tls : {
    _tls = .;
    . += 0x80;
    _tls_end = .;
    _tls_size = _tls_end - _tls;
    _tls_stack_limit = _tls + 0x30;
}

.bss : {
    _bss = .;
    *(.bss);
    _bss_end = .;
    _bss_size = _bss_end - _bss;
}

. = 0x5000;

.stack : {
    _stack = .;
    . += 0x4000;
    _stack_end = .;

    # Non-Rust functions use stack space but do not check the stack.  For
    # their sake, set Rust's checked stack limit somewhat above the true
    # limit.
    _stack_rust_limit = _stack + 0x1000;
}

. = 0x9000;

.image16 : {
    *(.text16);
    *(.data16);
}

.image : {
    *(.text);
    *(.text.*);
    *(.rodata);
    *(.rodata.*);
    *(.data);
    *(.data.*);
    *(.got);
    *(.got.*);
}

. = 0xc800;

.stage2 : {
    _stage2 = .;
    _stage2_segment = . >> 4;
    _stage2_reloc = 0x5000;                 # Address to copy stage2 to.
    _stage2_reloc_segment = _stage2_reloc >> 4;
    . += 0x73000;
    _stage2_end = .;
    _stage2_size = _stage2_end - _stage2;
    _stage2_para_size = _stage2_size >> 4;

    # When stage2 is moved, the src and dest regions overlap.  If the dest
    # were greater than the src, the move direction would need to change.
    ASSERT(_stage2_reloc <= _stage2 - 16, "stage2");
}

. = 0x7ff80;


# This section reserves memory for the routine that transfers control to
# stage2  That routine will move stage2 into place and potentially
# overwrite parts of stage1.

.transfer_code : {
    _transfer_code_segment = . >> 4;
    . += 0x80;
}
}
```

the errors is:
ld:src/stage1/stage1.ld:82: syntax error

i user cross compiler ld for linking and even normal gives the same error

Comment: Use C style comments in a linker script start with `/*` and end with `*/` . Don't use `#`

Comment: it worked bro.Thanks